# Apache not showing on server type while new server creation, What I've to do?

Tags: eclipse

I uninstalled my Apache tomcat and reinstalled it again. Now in new server creation I can't see Apache on server type list from Eclipse IDE. Is this issue among reinstalling tomcat or eclipse configuration issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v20gc.png)

Comment: Do you still have an entry for it on the Server Runtime Environments preference page?